# Unable to connect to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to connect my Android app to firebase using the tool provided by android studio but I am facing lots of trouble.

I have tried updating dependencies to latest latest google services but still the error persists
The error shown is **Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.**

Gradle/build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google() // here
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22


    minSdkVersion = 9
    targetSdkVersion = 23
}
```

Gradle/app
a

```
[pply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'



    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all my firebase/firestore implementation in my Grade/app file. don't know if some of these will help.

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth (GitHub provider)
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth-github:4.3.1'
```

Comment: Instead of using android studio tool to connect to database i tried to connect it manually using the help from firebase docs....Now its working .But thanks anyway